# div inside li-tag inside ul-tag has an unexpected stretch/resize behavior

Tags: html, css

My pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gtHpC

My goal with this pen was to have sort of stacked divs with text that is vertically and horizontally centered.

When you look at the gray or red/blue "stack" you see I reached this goal. But now comes the quirk.

When you resize the window in the height so the gray and red/blue stack gets shrinked in its height then sometimes there is a black (because the background of body is black) gap between the gray and red/blue stack. This gap is only visible depending at which point you resize.

Look at this image: [image]

The div around the red/blue stack has of height 24.50 % which I take as 100% for the 7 areas inside so each of the 7 'areas' inside this div have a height of **14.20 %**

I have alreay tried it with a value of 100% / 7 = 14.28571428571429 % instead of 14.20 % but this makes the situation not better.

The black gap is still there.

I use `box-sizing:border-box;` for all html elements thus the available 24.50% divided by 7 areas results in a clean number of 3.50% height for each area including the border or padding as I use latest chrome.

So I can not understand why is there the black gap when I resize?

**HTML**

```
<div id="responseChart" style="height:100%;">
<div style="font-size:8px;;height:24.50%;">
  <ul class="Stack" style="height:100%;width:150px;float:left;"> 
    <li><div class="vertical-center horizontal-center" style="background:blue;height:14.28571428571429%;border-bottom:white solid 1px;">1</div></li>
    <li><div class="vertical-center horizontal-center" style="background:red;height:14.28571428571429%;border-bottom:white solid 1px;">2</div></li>
    <li><div class="vertical-center horizontal-center" style="background:blue;height:14.28571428571429%;border-bottom:white solid 1px;">3</div></li>
    <li><div class="vertical-center horizontal-center" style="background:red;height:14.28571428571429%;border-bottom:white solid 1px;">4</div></li>
    <li><div class="vertical-center horizontal-center" style="background:blue;height:14.28571428571429%;border-bottom:white solid 1px;">5</div></li>
    <li><div class="vertical-center horizontal-center" style="background:red;height:14.28571428571429%;border-bottom:white solid 1px;">6</div></li>
    <li><div class="vertical-center horizontal-center" style="background:blue;height:14.28571428571429%;border-bottom:white solid 1px;">7</div></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="dummy"></div>
  <div style="height:100%;width:100px;float:left;">
    <div style="background:green;height:14.28571428571429%;border-bottom:white solid 1px;"></div>
    <div style="background:brown;height:14.28571428571429%;border-bottom:white solid 1px;"></div>
    <div style="background:green;height:14.28571428571429%;border-bottom:white solid 1px;"></div>
    <div style="background:brown;height:14.28571428571429%;border-bottom:white solid 1px;"></div>
    <div style="background:green;height:14.28571428571429%;border-bottom:white solid 1px;"></div>
    <div style="background:brown;height:14.28571428571429%;border-bottom:white solid 1px;"></div>
    <div style="background:green;height:14.28571428571429%;border-bottom:white solid 1px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="dummy"></div>
  <div style="height:100%;width:75px;float:left;">
    <div style="background:brown;height:14.28571428571429%;border-bottom:white solid 1px;"></div>
    <div style="background:green;height:14.28571428571429%;border-bottom:white solid 1px;"></div>
    <div style="background:brown;height:14.28571428571429%;border-bottom:white solid 1px;"></div>
    <div style="background:green;height:14.28571428571429%;border-bottom:white solid 1px;"></div>
    <div style="background:brown;height:14.28571428571429%;border-bottom:white solid 1px;"></div>
    <div style="background:green;height:14.28571428571429%;border-bottom:white solid 1px;"></div>
    <div style="background:brown;height:14.28571428571429%;border-bottom:white solid 1px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="dummy"></div>
</div>
<div style="background:darkred;height:1%;"></div>
<div style="height:74.50%;">
<div style="height:100%;" id="chartBody">
      <ul class="Stack" style="width:150px;">
        <li><div class="vertical-center horizontal-center" style="height:25%;">test1</div></li> 
        <li><div class="vertical-center horizontal-center" style="height:50%;">test2</div></li>
        <li><div class="vertical-center horizontal-center" style="height:25%;">test3</div></li>        
      </ul>
  <div class="dummy"></div>
      <div style="height:100%;width:100px;">
        <div style="height:100%;" >
          <div class="push-center diagram" style="background-color:#aa11cc;height:25%;">1</div>
          <div class="push-center diagram" style="background-color:#aa44cc;height:50%;">2</div>
          <div class="push-center diagram" style="background-color:#aa66cc;height:25%;">3</div>
        </div>       
      </div>   
      <div class="dummy"></div>  
      <div style="height:100%;width:75px;">
        <div style="height:100%;">
          <div class="push-center missingReplies" style="background-color:#fff;height:22%;">-1</div>
          <div class="push-center diagram" style="background-color:#ff99cc;height:11%;">3</div>
          <div class="push-center diagram" style="background-color:#ff33cc;height:44%;">44</div>
          <div class="push-center diagram" style="background-color:#ff66cc;height:23%;">36</div>
        </div>        
      </div>  
    <div class="dummy"></div>  
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

body, html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
padding:5px;  
  color:white;
  background:black;

}

*{ /* Every element which has a border or padding value puts this value inside the div */
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

#chartBody{
  height:100%;
  background:darkgray;
}

.missingReplies{
  border-top: gray dashed 1px;
  border-left: gray dashed 1px;
  border-right: gray dashed 1px;  
}

.clear{
  clear:both;
}

.diagram
{
  color:white; 
  font-weight:bold;
  border-bottom:white solid 1px;
}

#chartBody > div  {
  height:100%;  
  float:left;
}
.dummy{
  float:left;
  background:grey;
  height:100%;
  width:30px;

}
.Stack {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

    .Stack li {
        list-style: none;
        display: table-row;
    }

        .Stack li div {
            display: table-cell;
        }

.horizontal-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.vertical-center {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: What I found out is that IE10 and FF22 has not this problem! Only Chrome 28 ???

Comment: What I found out now again concerning Chrome: When I do NOT set the height for each of the 7 divs/segments and let chrome calculate their height implicitly then I do not have this gap.

Answer (score 0):

when you are using `display:table-row;` for `<li>` and `display:table;` for `<ul>` there is no need to set height to `<li>`, the height of parent tag (in this case `<ul>`) will divide between child tags (in this case `<li>`). look at this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZzTuK/1/)

*for more information you can see http://linuxandfriends.com/how-to-style-div-elements-as-tables/*